# Not able to receive json from Android app developed using C#

Tags: c#, php, android, json, xamarin

This is the code which I have written on the app side, which is being developed using `Xamarin`

```
HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ApiUrl);
objRequest.Method = "POST";
        objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";//"application/json;charset=utf-8";
        objRequest.Headers.Add("Authentication", "web60134");       
        UTF8Encoding utf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] arrRequest;
        arrRequest = utf8Encoding.GetBytes(JsonReq);
        objRequest.ContentLength = arrRequest.Length;
        Stream requestStream = objRequest.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(arrRequest, 0, arrRequest.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
        string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

This is the code written on the server side which is PHP

```
$recvd = $_POST['TH_ET_LoginProcess'];
$recvdArr = json_decode($recvd);
```

I tried using `file_get_contents("php://input")` but both the methods are returning null or nothing.

What is the best way to read JSON at web server using PHP in such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

**Best** is a quite subjective term.

However what I am successfully using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) in an Xamarin Android solution.

I also highly recommend [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/) and [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for troubleshooting your service.

**Regarding your code:**

You should be disposing those objects that are disposable, preferable with the 'using' statement. This includes HttpWebResponse object is as well as the Stream ones.